# Validating file size in upload using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-file-upload

I am trying to validate the file size in a File upload control in my ASP.NET application before even the submit button is clicked.

My max. size is 20kB. 
When I click on the button - even when the file is less than the max size - it still shows me the message

> File size should be less than 20kb

Below you find the corresponding code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#AdmissionUpload').on('change', function() {
            // Maximum file size allowed
            var maxFileSize = 20 // 20kb
            // Load the file upload controller to a variable
            var fileUpload = $('#AdmissionUpload');
            //Check if the file upload controller has value
            if (fileUpload.val() == '') {
                return false;
            } else {
                //Check if the file size is less than maximum file size
                if (fileUpload[0].files[0].size < maxFileSize) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    alert('File size should be less than 20kb')
                    fileUpload.val('');
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
        })

    </script>
```

Comment: This problem is not really related to `asp.net`.

Answer (score 0):

This line of code will return file size in bytes

```
fileUpload[0].files[0].size
```

and you are comparing it with 20 assuming it to be less than 20KB. So you need to adjust code something like

```
(fileUpload[0].files[0].size / 1024) < maxFileSize
```

Answer (score 0):

**Change**

```
            if (fileUpload[0].files[0].size < maxFileSize) {
                return true;
            } else {
                alert('File size should be less than 20kb')
                fileUpload.val('');
                return false;
            }
```

**To**

```
       var size = parseFloat(fileUpload[0].files[0].size / 1024).toFixed(2);
                //Check if the file size is less than maximum file size
                if (size < maxFileSize) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    alert('File size should be less than 20kb')
                    fileUpload.val('');
                    return false;
                }
```